# How to access a cookie from callback function in Dash by Plotly?

Tags: python, cookies, plotly-dash

I have a simple Dash callback function like following:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('test_output', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('test_input', 'value')]):
def process(val):
    return html.Div('test')
```

And now I'm going to set some cookies. As we can see in the source code of Dash, wrapper function makes usual Flask Response object with serialized returned data:

```
def wrap_func(func):
    def add_context(*args, **kwargs):

        output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        response = {
            'response': {
                'props': {
                    output.component_property: output_value
                }
            }
        }

        return flask.Response(
            json.dumps(response,
                       cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder),
            mimetype='application/json'
        )

    self.callback_map[callback_id]['callback'] = add_context

    return add_context
```

So if this code were a part of my project, I would use `Response.set_cookie` here.

The situation with sessions seems to be different - I can access and modify session objects from the wrapped function that results in modifying `session` cookie.

How can I set and get cookies from Dash callback? Maybe Flask has a way to do such thing without directly creating Response object?

**UPDATE**

I've created an issue for this:
https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/182

And pull request to add this functionality:
https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality you are looking for was ultimately merged in:
https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/623 (on March 4th 2019)

Their example on how to set a cookie looks like this:

```
@app.callback(Output('output', 'children'), [Input('input', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    dash.callback_context.response.set_cookie(
        'dash cookie', value + ' - cookie')
    return value + ' - output'
```