# Save a cookie from callback function in Dash by Plotly

Tags: flask, cookies, callback, plotly-dash

Looked at the following post explaining how to store cookies:
[How to access a cookie from callback function in Dash by Plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945841/how-to-access-a-cookie-from-callback-function-in-dash-by-plotly)
I'm trying to replicate this and I'm not able to store/retrieve cookies.What is wrong in the simple example below ? There are no error messages, but when debugging, the all_cookies dict is empty, while I'd expect it to have at least one member 'dash cookie'.

```
@app.callback(
    Output(ThemeSwitchAIO.ids.switch("theme"), "value"),
    Input("url-login", "pathname"),
)
def save_load_cookie(value):
    dash.callback_context.response.set_cookie('dash cookie', '1 - cookie')
    all_cookies = dict(flask.request.cookies)
    return dash.no_update
```

Please note the app is running on my local machine via the standard flask server:

```
app.run_server(host='127.0.0.1', port=80, debug=True,
               use_debugger=False, use_reloader=False, passthrough_errors=True)
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `dash.no_update` and return a value to an output?

Comment: touche... it makes it work! I'm not completely sure I understand the logic of why response should only be triggered on callback update (would be keen to hear on the sense of the design choice) but that's good to know. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @coralvanda, the callback needs to return a value instead of dash.no_update. Code should simply be:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(ThemeSwitchAIO.ids.switch("theme"), "value"),
    Input("url-login", "pathname"),
)
def save_load_cookie(value):
    dash.callback_context.response.set_cookie('dash cookie', '1 - cookie')
    all_cookies = dict(flask.request.cookies)
    return value
```